# Characters not displayed correctly in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing my app in **codeigniter**
I got my characters like `ī, ū, ā ,š` etc . When i insert them in database i do `utf8_encode('$this->input->post('mypostdata')')` . When i echo them out on page i do `utf8_decode($enterie->row('myrow'))`, everything is displaying just fine. But when i open database, all those characters are displayed like Ä« or Å¡  etc. I got my database collation set to **utf8_general_ci** . Codeigniter db config file

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

i have checked db charset with `SHOW CREATE DATABASE`DB_NAME , i got /*!`40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8` */

I searched information and found something about my.cnf file, but my page and database is hosted on ipage.com .

So what are options i should check ?

Comment: It looks like the post data is already utf8 encoded

Comment: "when I open the database": how do you open the database?

Comment: in browser with phpmyadmin (as i said my host is ipage.com).

Comment: *(your host could allow direct connections, hence my question)* You must have something wrong in your table definition. Please post the full structure of the table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE the_table;`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already faced this issue. You need just one line of code using `iconv()` function:

Try this:

```
$post_data1= $this->input->post('mypostdata'); //data with ī, ū, ā ,š
$post_data= iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $post_data1); //now it will become i, u, a etc.
```

now send `$post_data` to database.

and it will work.

Comment: Doesn't work..... with this method, my characters are displayed like ??? marks . Do i need to add some php headers? if yes, then where.

p.s also i cant echo out data correctly. they echo with ???? marks

Comment: you need to add above line of code in controller.. Could you please show your controller function?